# Using R's integrate() with functions from R and Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, numerical-integration

Function `dt` in R can sometimes throw warning messages depending on the values used in the computation.

For example, `dt(1.424781, 1486, -5)` shows

```
Warning messages:
1: In dt(1.424781, 1486, -5) :
  full precision may not have been achieved in 'pnt{final}'
2: In dt(1.424781, 1486, -5) :
  full precision may not have been achieved in 'pnt{final}'
```

This issue is exactly the same as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183938/rs-t-distribution-says-full-precision-may-not-have-been-achieved).

The last post in that thread suggests to use rcpp to get better precision. I did, and it works well.

I saved the rcpp code in file `boost_t.cpp`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/math/distributions/non_central_t.hpp> 

using namespace boost::math;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double dnct(const double x, const double df, const double ncp) {
  non_central_t dist(df, ncp);
  return pdf(dist, x);
}
```

and then in R simply do

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("boost_t.cpp")
dnct(1.424781, 1486, -5)
[1] 4.393078e-10
```

What I would like to do is to use `dnct()` inside `integrate()` in R.

When I try I get an error. For example:

```
integrate(function(delta) dnct(1.2, 20, delta), lower = 0, upper = 1)
```

gives this error: `Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=21]`.

I was expecting a similar behavior that I have with `dt`:

```
integrate(function(delta) dt(1.2, 20, delta), lower = 0, upper = 1)

0.2964214 with absolute error < 3.3e-15
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, I see now that the answer you refer to was written by me. I don't remember that at all. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function argument over which you integrate must be vectorized:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/math/distributions/non_central_t.hpp> 

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector dnct(const double x, const double df, const NumericVector ncp) {

  R_xlen_t n = ncp.length();
  NumericVector y(n);

  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    boost::math::non_central_t dist(df, ncp[i]);
    y[i] = boost::math::pdf(dist, x);
  }

  return y;
}

/*** R
integrate(function(delta) dnct(1.2, 20, delta), lower = 0, upper = 1)
*/
```

It is left as an exercise for the reader to also vectorize the `x` and `df` arguments.

Comment: It works, thanks! 
I would not be able to code this as I do not know C nor C++.

Comment: It's really not that difficult. I'm not good in C++ myself but you can learn the basics in a few hours.

Comment: Nice Boost integration example.  Only nit I'd have is the dual `using namespace` which I find dicey.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the feedback. You mean the risk of name collisions, right?

Comment: Right. Even now in your edited example: is `pdf()` really from `Rcpp` or does it need the Boost namespave?